# Roll Off Profile

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

df= pd.DataFrame({'date':['2017-12-31','2017-12-31'],'type':['Asset','Asset'],'Amount':[365,45],'Maturity Date':['2019-01-02','2018-07-02']})
df
```

I want create a "roll-off" profile that shows the first three months and the next 5 quarters. I have been able to do this using the following piece of code:

```
#First Month
df['2018-01-31']=0
df.loc[df['Maturity Date']>'2018-01-31','2018-01-31']=df['Amount']

#Second Month
df['2018-02-28']=0
df.loc[df['Maturity Date']>'2018-02-28','2018-02-28']=df['Amount']

#Third Month
df['2018-03-31']=0
df.loc[df['Maturity Date']>'2018-03-31','2018-03-31']=df['Amount']

#First Quarter
df['2018-06-30']=0
df.loc[df['Maturity Date']>'2018-06-30','2018-06-30']=df['Amount']

#Second Quarter
df['2018-09-30']=0
df.loc[df['Maturity Date']>'2018-09-30','2018-09-30']=df['Amount']
```

I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to achieve this ? Specifically, I wanted a way to:

1. Not manually enter the first three months and subsequent quarters
2. Avoid repeating similar code for each month and quarter

Comment: Can you explain more `and subsequent quarters` ? I try dynamically generate it by last month, but I get first and second quarter instead second and third. So my solution  was shifting - there was generate 3 quarters and first was removed by `c2[1:]`. Is it what you need?

Comment: I see you create new question, so my solution does not work?

Comment: Hello,Your solution worked fine, but it was a slightly different problem. In the question above each new date is a separate column. However, in the new question each new date is a separate row. I tried using melt but failed.

Comment: So need melt columns with datetimes?

Comment: I don't need a separate column for each datapoint. So just one additional column that has the dates ( 2018-01-31,2018-02-28,2018-03-31) and one and the amount field remains the same. Other than having so many columns, I wanted rows. Hope that clarifies. Thanks a lot for your help ! Much appreciated.

Comment: So there is only one row of data like in new question sample?

Comment: Yes. the new question has the exact output that I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
#convert to datetime if necessary
df['Maturity Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Maturity Date'])

d = '2018-01-31'
#generate first month and next quarters
c1 = pd.date_range(d, periods=3, freq='M')
c2 =  pd.date_range(c1[-1], periods=3, freq='Q')
#join together
c = c1.union(c2[1:])

#compare column with joined datetimes
m = df['Maturity Date'].values[:, None] > c.values
#get values by boolean mask
b = np.where(m, df['Amount'].values[:, None], 0)
#join output df to original, format columns with strftime
df1 = df.join(pd.DataFrame(b, columns=c.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')))
print (df1)
   Amount Maturity Date        date   type  2018-01-31  2018-02-28  \
0     365    2019-01-02  2017-12-31  Asset         365         365   
1      45    2018-07-02  2017-12-31  Asset          45          45   

   2018-03-31  2018-06-30  2018-09-30  
0         365         365         365  
1          45          45           0
```